# Building a plot for each unique value of a column

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, dplyr

I have data with multiple variables and I want to make a plot for each of the unique values in one column. I looked at multiple answers on here for similar problems but I couldnt solve mine.

An example of the dataset looks as follows:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), Date = c("01/02/20", "01/03/20", 
"01/05/20", "01/02/20", "01/05/20"), New = c(10, 5, 5, 10, 5), 
    Old = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20), Percentage = c(0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 
    0.5, 0.25)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
ID      Date          New    Old   Percentage 
1       01/02/20      10     20    0.5
1       01/03/20      5      20    0.25
1       01/05/20      5      20    0.25
2       01/02/20      10     20    0.5
2       01/05/20      5      20    0.25
```

I wanted to do a for loop that goes over the unique values of ID and plot the new and old vs date. Also maybe another facet that should the percent change but mainly the first comparison plot. I tried first to make it as date vs new as follow:

```
for (ii in unique(data$ID)) {
  plt <- ggplot(data %>% filter(ID == ii),
                aes(x = "Month",
                    y = "New")) +
    geom_point(color = "dodgerblue3") + 
    theme_minimal()
  print(plt)

}
```

The result basically gave me a on point plot which I didnt understand. How can I add the Old comparison and also another plot for the percentage.

Comment: you cannot have aes(x="Month", y="New" ..), it should be aes(x=Month,y=New..)? Then again, how come Monthis not in the dataset you showed?

Comment: And please be more precise about what you're actually looking for. Otherwise it is really hard to help you.

Comment: I'll post a solution below I really don't know if it actually is, what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is this somewhat what you are looking for?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
    mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = c("New", "Old"), names_to = "newOrOld") %>%
    ggplot(aes(Date, value, colour = newOrOld)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(. ~ ID)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

-Regarding your loop, I think you could just use a facet function instead

-About the old/new question, I think that your problem comes from your data structure, which is not tidy.

try this :

```
## get tidy data
tidy_data <- data %>% pivot_longer(c("New", "Old"), names_to = "Age", values_to = "Number")

## get the plots (facet_wrap is used to have multiple plots)
plt <- ggplot(tidy_data, aes(x = Date, y = Number, color = Age)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ ID)
plt
```